# In Mongoid how can I use "created_at" as my own attribute?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am working on a Mongo document store for a data feed (using Mongoid in Ruby).  The feed itself has a created and last updated set of fields. I want to store them in my Mongoid document as "created_at" and "updated_at" but Mongoid internally doesn't like having those as explicit attributes of my own since they are the field names when you declare "include Mongoid::Timestamps" on a document.

Is there a way to use "created_at" and "updated_at" as my own fields? Or do I need to just punt and figure out different names for these fields?

I tried just defining those fields, and it works when the document is first created, but when I update it, I get something like:

```
/mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic/modifiers.rb:121:in `add_operation': undefined method `each' for "2015-05-18 14:55:07":String (NoMethodError)
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic/modifiers.rb:87:in `block in set'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic/modifiers.rb:84:in `each_pair'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic/modifiers.rb:84:in `set'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic.rb:353:in `generate_atomic_updates'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic.rb:134:in `block in atomic_updates'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic.rb:132:in `each'
from /mnt/task/__gems__/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/atomic.rb:132:in `atomic_updates'
```

In other words, it is trying to do an iteration over the string, probably because within Mongoid it "believes" that it's a Date object, even though I've defined it as a String.

I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: I want to store them as Strings, is all. So I don't wnat to use Mongoid::Timestamps but then when I have "created_at" as a field name, it conflicts.

Comment: Hi mu...  this is what I'm running into as a problem. I don't include the Mongoid::Timestamps and just declare created_at as a String field, but within Mongoid it still has issues (like the error above) because it still wants to treat it as a date/time object, not a string like I've declared. I'm now thinking that this is just a bug in Mongoid and there isn't any workaround... other than naming the field something other than "created_at"

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.

First, if you want to set created_at or updated_at manually instead of automatically, you can set them on the object and then use "timeless.save" instead of "save".

Second, it turns out that the problem was because the object with the timestamps as String type was an embedded object but I forgot to do the "embedded_in" reverse relationship. Once that was done, it all worked.

So this was ultimately just an issue with me not understanding the embedded relationship correctly. I'll leave this just on the off-chance someone else could benefit from this.